# Why is static Used in Importing Libraries

Tags: android

[What is the purpose of using static in importing libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd12r.png)

Comment: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd12r.png"/>

Comment: Please include the relevant parts as _text_ and not as image.

Comment: @answerers: Please do not encourage such questions by actually answering them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static import is a feature introduced in the Java 5 programming language that allows members (fields and methods) defined in a class as public static to be used in Java code; without specifying the class in which the field is defined.

The static import feature facilitate the java programmer to access any static member of a class directly. There is no need to qualify it by the class name.

Sample Example

```
import static java.lang.System.*;    
class StaticImportExample{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  

   out.println("Hello");//Now no need of System.out  
   out.println("Java");  

 }   
}
```